# Spring JPA not implementing/autowiring repository despite @EnableJpaRepositories annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired

I'm getting an exception when I start my application, where Spring complain about UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'controlRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.oak.api.finance.repository.ControlRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
```

My application is organized in this format:

1. I declared my repository interfaces, with the proper Spring JPA annotations:

   ```
   @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "exchange", path = "exchanges")
   public interface ControlRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Control, Long> { 
   }
   ```
2. I annotated the `EntryPoint` class that contains the `main` method

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.oak.api.finance.model.dto"})
   @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.oak.api.finance.repository"})
   public class EntryPoint {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(EntryPoint.class);
           logger.info("Starting application");

           ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
   //      SpringApplication.run(EntryPoint.class, args);

           ctx.getBean(ApplicationServer.class).start();
       }
   ```
3. I used `@Autowired` to inject my repository into my spring config (java based) `ApplicationConfig` class:

   ```
   @Autowired 
   private ControlRepository controlRepository;
   @Autowired
   private CompanyRepository companyRepository;
   @Autowired
   private SectorRepository sectorRepository;
   ```

Essentially I want to control the dependency on Spring and limit it to a couple of packages, (the repositories, the java config, and the program entry point - EntryPoint)

I assumed that, by specifying @EnableJpaRepositories with the package where my repositories are located, spring would create a proxy for my repository and instantiate an instance of that, and that by the time I call :

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class)
```

The repositories instances would be present in the beans poole and would be possible to autowire them into my `ApplicationConfig` context, and then inject them into my controller.

This is clearly not happening, and Spring is complaining about the missing Bean to autowire, but I'm not sure what am I missing.

Below a snapshot of my packages: 
[image]
any ideas?

Comment: In which package is the Control class. You set Entity scan do model.dto which seems odd to me.

Comment: The Control class as well as the rest of the Entity classes are in: com.oak.api.finance.model.dto , dto is where I put all my Entity classes..

Comment: Add SpringApplication.run(EntryPoint.class); after the logging and remove the ApplicationContext part. Than ensure that your ApplicationConfig class is annotated with @Configuration

Comment: that works when I stop trying to create the `ApplicationContext` (from the `ApplicationConfig`) which is ok until the point where I need to get hold of the `ApplicationServer` bean (instance of class `ApplicationServer`), to call start() on it. I pointed to the `ApplicationConfig` using the `@ComponentScan` and I can see my beans instantiated. But if I try `@Autowired ApplicationServer app;` it doesn't get injected, and if I call `start()` I get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Implement the CommandLineRunner interface. Autowired beans should than be available in the run method. Oh I just see your package structure is odd. You need to set the component scan to com.oak -> scanBasePackages argument of @SpringBootApplication

Comment: that did the trick! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your repositories are not being scanned, so as a result beans are not getting created. Can you try removing these 2 annotations

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.oak.api.finance.model.dto"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.oak.api.finance.repository"})
```

And keep only `@SpringBootApplication`. If this is not working, you might need to check the package structure (if possible paste a screenshot here)

## Edit 1

replace `@SpringBootApplication` with

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.oak")
```

## Edit2

Use

```
 new SpringApplicationBuilder() 
        .sources(SpringBootApp.class) 
        .web(false) 
        .run(args);
```

Or use CommandLineRunner after changing ComponentScan path to "com.oak" as mh-dev suggested

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. I'm trying to put all in github, if that turns out complicated I'll try with a screenshot. (I thought it was already on github, but it looks like I created a local branch - not sure how to put that on github, I'll see)

Comment: OK I couldn't sort out github now, I added a screenshot

Comment: I think this is the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619532/configuration-using-annotation-springbootapplication

Comment: Solution: Since your package structure is non-convntional , I would replace "@SpringbootApplication" annotation with '@Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan("com.oak") '...

Comment: that works only if I stop trying to create the `ApplicationContext` (from the `ApplicationConfig`) which is ok until the point where I need to get hold of the `ApplicationServer` bean, to call `start()` on it. I pointed to the ApplicationConfig using the `@ComponentScan` and I can see my beans instantiated. But if I try  `@Autowired ApplicationServer app;` it doesn't get injected, and if I call `start()` I get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Essentially it looks like instantiating the ApplicationContext is the root cause of the problem, and without that I don't know how to get hold of the starting point bean

Comment: Probably I failed to understand your use case... got a question,  why can't you start the application like this 

`public class EntryPoint {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(EntryPoint.class, args);
 }
}`
And let spring take care of starting the embedded servlet container (tomcat/jetty) for you.

Comment: Sorry, ApplicationServer is just another class with a method called start and that's what I need to call to start the application. (there is no web application or anything like that)

Comment: Ok.. have you annotated ApplicationServer class with @Component  (@Service or similar annotation which will tell spring to create a bean of that class)?

Comment: The comment from mh-dev solved it, to answer your question, no I instantiate it as a `@Bean` in the `@Config (ApplicationConfig)`. Anyway now it's working