# Spring Boot + JavaFx autowiring doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

Yesterday I tried to create project connecting Spring Boot and JavaFX. I was basing on http://www.greggbolinger.com/let-spring-be-your-javafx-controller-factory/

So I created a project and when I run application spring context is created and JavaFx application is run. But the problem is when I try to create some beans e.g using @Repository annotation. When I am autowiring then value is null.

**CarGarageApplication.java**

```
package com.car.garage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.car.garage.dao.UsersRepository;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.car.garage.dao")
public class CarGarageApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext mainContext;
    private Parent rootNode;

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        mainContext = SpringApplication.run(CarGarageApplication.class);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/WelcomePage.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(mainContext::getBean);
        rootNode = loader.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootNode));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println(usersRepository);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        mainContext.close();
    }
}
```

**UsersRepository.java**

```
package com.car.garage.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.car.garage.model.User;

@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.car.garage.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

`mainContext.getBean(UsersRepository.class)` return correct bean instance of UsersRepository but why @Autowired doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried the steps proposed by this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118876/spring-jpa-not-implementing-autowiring-repository-despite-enablejparepositories

Comment: Yes, after that there is the same problem

Comment: You should not directly autowire repository class in a boot class. there should be some upper layer like component class which autowire this repository class.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you for answer. Is there any reason why it is not allowed ?

Comment: It's mandatory to have SPRING STEREOTYPES class(@Component, @Service like that) from where you are autowiring the another class and in your main class which is boot class there is no such stereotype annotation present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should follow below approach to autowire repository class. because It's mandatory to have SPRING STEREOTYPES class(@Component, @Service like that) from where you are autowiring the another class

```
@Component
 public class Anotherclass{

     @Autowired
     private UsersRepository usersRepository;
}
```