# What is SpringBootApplication functionality?

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations

I understand that `@SpringBootApplication` is used to mark the main class of  a spring application.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619532/configuration-using-annotation-springbootapplication) I see that it "is equivalent to using `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`". But why is there needed a `@Configuration` if it is already made automatically with  `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: what do you mean by "why is there needed a @Configuration". If you use `@SpringBootApplication` you don't need to use `@Configuration` on that class

Comment: downvoting because Spring has excellent documentation that you should read before asking a question on STackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EnableAutoConfiguration means Spring boot will look what libraries you use and try to set up beans accordingly. It has nothing to do with @Configuration.