# Spring Boot scanBasePackages unable to find beans from dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have following:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.my.package","com.my.package.mylibrary"})
@EnableAsync
@EnableSwagger2
@ServletComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MySpringBootApplication {....}
```

This application has package `com.my.package`, and it also has a library dependency containing spring beans I want to autowire in this application, and those beans are in package `com.my.package.mylibrary` inside library.

So I have put both for `scanBasePackages`. But Spring is not able to find beans from the library?

Edit:

From library, I have:

```
package com.my.package.mylibrary.repository;
....
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<..., ....> {....}
```

In application, I have:

```
package com.my.package.controller;
....
@RestController
public class MyController {....}
```

MySpringBootApplication resides in com.my.package.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/my/package/mylibrary/repository/MyRepository
    at com.my.package.MySpringBootApplication.main(MySpringBootApplication.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.package.mylibrary.repository.MyRepository
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

I added @EnableJpaRepositories for repository package. Now I see error related to entity MyEntity which MyRepository is based upon.

```
"java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.my.package.mylibrary.domain.MyEntity not present
```

So I added @EntityScan for "com.my.package.mylibrary.domain", but that makes application stuck infinitely.

Comment: Let's show few classes in package `com.my.package`, `com.my.package.mylibrary`!

Comment: Please add the error message that is displayed

Comment: The @SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration and ComponentScan with their default attributes: [...]. If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation.

Comment: But it is not able to detect beans from dependent jar.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619532/configuration-using-annotation-springbootapplication

Comment: It will automatically pick you don't need to add scanPackages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to add `scanBasePackages` attribute in `@SpringBootApplication` as the base package is `com.my.package`.

If package is totally different, then you could have added it.

Spring Boot will automatically pick up the bean if the base package is same.

There is something called as **separation of concerns** that you should follow when you are writing code.

---

Update your MySpringBootApplication class to this  :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
public class MySpringBootApplication {....}
```

Create a separate config for asynchronous method execution.

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAsync
 public class AsynchronousConfig {.....}
```

Create a separate config class for Swagger 2.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {....}
```

Create separate config to exclude configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ExcludeConfigurationFile {....}
```

**Note:** Spring boot auto configuration will automatically pick up these `@Configuration` files

This should work.

Comment: I have removed ServletComponentScan. EntityScan and EnableJpaRepositories. I still see java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.my.package.mylibrary.domain.MyEntity not present. Somehow spring is not able to load entity class.

Comment: @Mandroid Do you have this entity com.my.package.mylibrary.domain.MyEntity ?

Comment: Yes. MyRepository is defined for it.

Comment: @Mandroid Add the code of com.my.package.mylibrary.domain.MyEntity ?

Comment: @Mandroid Check whether MyEntity class exists or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to scan the packages seperately and change your JpaRepository to CrudRepository. The configuration to seperate the layer is as follow.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.my.package.controller"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.my.package.mylibrary.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.my.package.mylibrary.domain"})
public class MySpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySpringBootApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```