# Spring Kotlin @ConfigurationProperties for data class defined in dependency

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-kotlin

I've got a library that has a configuration class (no spring configuration class) defined as a data class. I want a Bean of that configuration which can be configured via application.properties. The problem is that I don't know how to tell Spring to create ConfigurationProperties according to that external data class. I am not the author of the configuration class so I can't annotate the class itself. @ConfigurationProperties in conjunction with @Bean does not work as the properties are immutable. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change scan packages to inlcude the packages that do you want.

```
 @SpringBootApplication( scanBasePackages = )
```

take a look this:
[Configuration using annotation @SpringBootApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619532/configuration-using-annotation-springbootapplication)

Comment: Sorry this wasn't very clear in my description but the class is no spring configuration class.

Comment: use  
  @Bean
   public AppName getAppName(@Value("${app.name}") String appName) {

    return () -> appName;
   }

Comment: yeah but for a lot of options this would be a lot of boilerplate and I thought there might be a convenient way to mark a class of an external dependency to be a ConfigurationPorperties class.

Comment: I understood, but if your external class doesn't have a spring annotation, this is only way to do this.

Comment: Seems to be the only possibility

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, do you need a way to turn a third-party object into a bean with properties from your `application.properties` file ?

Given an `application.properties` file:

```
third-party-config.params.simpleParam=foo
third-party-config.params.nested.nestedOne=bar1
third-party-config.params.nested.nestedTwo=bar2
```

Create a class to receive your params from properties file

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "third-party-config")
data class ThirdPartConfig(val params: Map<String, Any>)
```

Here is an example of the object that you want to use

```
class ThirdPartyObject(private val simpleParam: String, private val nested: Map<String, String>) {

fun printParams() =
    "This is the simple param: $simpleParam and the others nested ${nested["nestedOne"]} and ${nested["nestedTwo"]}"

}
```

Create the configuration class with a method that turns your third-party object into an injectable bean.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
class ThirdPartObjectConfig(private val thirdPartConfig: ThirdPartConfig) {

@Bean
fun thirdPartyObject(): ThirdPartyObject {
    return ThirdPartObject(
        simpleParam = thirdPartConfig.params["simpleParam"].toString(),
        nested = getMapFromAny(
            thirdPartConfig.params["nested"]
                ?: throw IllegalStateException("'nested' parameter must be declared in the app propertie file")
            )
        )
    }

    private fun getMapFromAny(unknownType: Any): Map<String, String> {
        val asMap = unknownType as Map<*, *>
        return mapOf(
            "nestedOne" to asMap["nestedOne"].toString(),
            "nestedTwo" to asMap["nestedTwo"].toString()
        )
    }
}
```

So now you can inject your third-party object as a bean with custom configurated params from your `application.properties` files

```
@SpringBootApplication
class StackoverflowAnswerApplication(private val thirdPartObject: ThirdPartObject): CommandLineRunner {
  override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
    println("Running --> ${thirdPartObject.printParams()}")
  }
}
```