# Spring Boot Application Shutting Down automatically on startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have exported a Spring Boot application from **https://start.spring.io/** but when I start it on IntelliJ it gets shut down.

I think I am doing something wrong with the configuration part.

I have found a solution somewhere that it gets shutdown because there is no controller present. But I added one and still same issue occured.

**APPLICATION.PROPERTIES**

```
server.port=9081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GEEK_DEV
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

[image]

[image]

Logs are provided below:

**RUN LOG**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=60154:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\Development Work\Projects\GeekDev\geekdev\target\classes;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.11\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.23\spring-web-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.23\spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.23\spring-expression-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-amqp\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-amqp-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.3.23\spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\amqp\spring-rabbit\2.4.7\spring-rabbit-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\amqp\spring-amqp\2.4.7\spring-amqp-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\rabbitmq\amqp-client\5.14.2\amqp-client-5.14.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jdbc\2.4.3\spring-data-jdbc-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-relational\2.4.3\spring-data-relational-2.4.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.7.3\spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.11.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.17\byte-buddy-1.12.17.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.6\jaxb-runtime-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.6\txw2-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.7.3\spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.23\spring-aspects-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-graphql\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-graphql-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\graphql\spring-graphql\1.0.2\spring-graphql-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-integration\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-integration-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-core\5.5.15\spring-integration-core-5.5.15.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.23\spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.7.3\spring-security-config-5.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.7.3\spring-security-core-5.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\5.7.3\spring-security-crypto-5.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-oauth2-client\5.7.3\spring-security-oauth2-client-5.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-oauth2-core\5.7.3\spring-security-oauth2-core-5.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\oauth2-oidc-sdk\9.35\oauth2-oidc-sdk-9.35.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\github\stephenc\jcip\jcip-annotations\1.0-1\jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\content-type\2.2\content-type-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\lang-tag\1.6\lang-tag-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-oauth2-jose\5.7.3\spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\nimbus-jose-jwt\9.22\nimbus-jose-jwt-9.22.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-oauth2-resource-server\5.7.3\spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-security-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.23\spring-aop-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.7.3\spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web-services\2.7.4\spring-boot-starter-web-services-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\messaging\saaj\saaj-impl\1.5.3\saaj-impl-1.5.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\soap\jakarta.xml.soap-api\1.4.2\jakarta.xml.soap-api-1.4.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.3\stax-ex-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\ws\jakarta.xml.ws-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.ws-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\jakarta\jws\jakarta.jws-api\2.1.0\jakarta.jws-api-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-oxm\5.3.23\spring-oxm-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-ws-core\3.1.3\spring-ws-core-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-xml\3.1.3\spring-xml-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\apache\kafka\kafka-streams\3.1.2\kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\apache\kafka\kafka-clients\3.1.2\kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\github\luben\zstd-jni\1.5.0-4\zstd-jni-1.5.0-4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\lz4\lz4-java\1.8.0\lz4-java-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.1.8.4\snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\rocksdb\rocksdbjni\6.22.1.1\rocksdbjni-6.22.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.4\jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.4\jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.4\jackson-core-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-amqp\5.5.15\spring-integration-amqp-5.5.15.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-http\5.5.15\spring-integration-http-5.5.15.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-jdbc\5.5.15\spring-integration-jdbc-5.5.15.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-jpa\5.5.15\spring-integration-jpa-5.5.15.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.23\spring-orm-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-kafka\5.5.15\spring-integration-kafka-5.5.15.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-security\5.5.15\spring-integration-security-5.5.15.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\integration\spring-integration-ws\5.5.15\spring-integration-ws-5.5.15.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\kafka\spring-kafka\2.8.9\spring-kafka-2.8.9.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.23\spring-context-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.23\spring-tx-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.3.3\spring-retry-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\session\spring-session-jdbc\2.7.0\spring-session-jdbc-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\session\spring-session-core\2.7.0\spring-session-core-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.23\spring-jcl-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.7.4\spring-boot-devtools-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.4\spring-boot-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.4\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.30\mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.4.8\json-smart-2.4.8.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\2.4.8\accessors-smart-2.4.8.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.1\asm-9.1.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.23\spring-core-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.23\spring-beans-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\reactor-core\3.4.23\reactor-core-3.4.23.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.4\reactive-streams-1.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\graphql-java\graphql-java\18.3\graphql-java-18.3.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\com\graphql-java\java-dataloader\3.1.2\java-dataloader-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Avrio01\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.9.3\antlr4-runtime-4.9.3.jar" com.geek.dev.geekdev.GeekdevApplication
01:34:54.269 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@102bcb5e

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.4)

2022-10-01 01:34:54.742  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] com.geek.dev.geekdev.GeekdevApplication  : Starting GeekdevApplication using Java 1.8.0_202 on DESKTOP-M1309TG with PID 20500 (D:\Development Work\Projects\GeekDev\geekdev\target\classes started by Avrio01 in D:\Development Work\Projects\GeekDev\geekdev)
2022-10-01 01:34:54.743  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] com.geek.dev.geekdev.GeekdevApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-10-01 01:34:54.802  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-10-01 01:34:55.469  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2022-10-01 01:34:55.469  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-10-01 01:34:55.469  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2022-10-01 01:34:55.485  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2022-10-01 01:34:55.485  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-10-01 01:34:55.485  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 0 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-10-01 01:34:55.664  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2022-10-01 01:34:55.669  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2022-10-01 01:34:56.152  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-10-01 01:34:56.162  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-10-01 01:34:56.253  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-10-01 01:34:56.439  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-10-01 01:34:56.545  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-10-01 01:34:56.610  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.11.Final
2022-10-01 01:34:56.808  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-10-01 01:34:57.047  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2022-10-01 01:34:57.295  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-10-01 01:34:57.301  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-10-01 01:34:58.379  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-10-01 01:34:58.506  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2022-10-01 01:34:58.506  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2022-10-01 01:34:58.506  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2022-10-01 01:34:58.516  INFO 20500 --- [  restartedMain] com.geek.dev.geekdev.GeekdevApplication  : Started GeekdevApplication in 4.233 seconds (JVM running for 4.911)
2022-10-01 01:34:58.533  INFO 20500 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2022-10-01 01:34:58.533  INFO 20500 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2022-10-01 01:34:58.533  INFO 20500 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2022-10-01 01:34:58.533  INFO 20500 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-10-01 01:34:58.548  INFO 20500 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-10-01 01:34:58.555  INFO 20500 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

** POM.XML **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.geek.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>geekdev</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>geekdev</name>
    <description>Geek Dev</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have tried playing with dependencies but nothing helped.

Comment: But you do have a class in there that is a `@SpringBootApplication`? And a `@Controller` or `@RestController` that's in a package that is under the application's package? The code that finds controller defaults to scanning packages that are children of the application. The logs show nothing regarding spring web mvc. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ are docs you can follow

Comment: I have edited my question. can you please check?

Comment: IntelliJ Ultimate!? (Since "CE" has "no spring support".and could explain "weird behaviour" ..esp. not knowing you "run configuration" + devtools)

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is not in a subpackage of the application.
You either need to move it to `com.geek.dev.geekdev.controllers` or you need to adjust the path spring scans for controllers and other components. By default it will only look into `com.geek.dev.geekdev.*`

You can change the path by adding the `scanBasePackages` property to `@SpringBootApplication` like

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.geek.dev")
```

---

original answer but this apparently doesn't work

You can change the path by adding `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.geek.dev")` to your application class next to `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: I did it but still same issue. ```package com.geek.dev.geekdev;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.geek.dev")
public class GeekdevApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(GeekdevApplication.class, args);
 }

}
```

Comment: have the logs changed? Is there anything regarding dispatcher servlet, web, mvc, ..?

Comment: No the logs are still the same

Comment: if you put `@PostCreate void init() { System.out.println("I'm alive"); }` inside your controller, is that printing something? If the controller is found as component it should do that in the post create phase.

Comment: Can you check my pom.xml?

Comment: @Jawad-Dev another thing you can try, if you remove `@ComponentScan` but change the bootapplication one to `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.geek.dev")`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39747914/995891 - your pom is full of "duplicates", e.g. you don't need data-jpa and data-jdbc and simple jdbc at the same time. But that should make no difference. But you can try with a minimal set by using just spring-starter-web from the initializer. Would also put a print into the `main` method to check that it's actually executed

Comment: Thanks mate. ```@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.geek.dev")``` worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the Controller with

```
@RequestMapping("")
```

also

For example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path")
public class User{ ...
```

Comment: I did it. same  issue

Comment: Please try use 
@EnableAutoConfiguration
In GeekdevApplication class.

Comment: Still not resolved. I have shared my application.properties. Have a look at that file too.

Comment: Where? I don't see.
Did you configure the database connection?
If you don't have it, it could be that, due to the fact that you added the dependencies

Comment: Sorry. Please change port: 

server.port=9081
to 8080


It may be that another service is using this port

Comment: I have checked it no service is using this port.

Comment: It seems that spring doesn't find the controller bean, and it doesn't even initialize like the web server. At least the service port should appear in the Java log.

Comment: Please move you controller to same package of Geekdevapplication

Comment: Can you check the springboot function in pom.xml?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, spring doesn't read packages outside the main package.

If so, move it to com.geek.dev.geekdev.controllers

Comment: Ooohh in your pom.xml, change 
<packaging>war</packaging>
to
<packaging>jar</packaging>

Comment: ```@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.geek.dev")``` worked for me! thank for your inputs.

Comment: Great!!! good luck!